# Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 Error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

Im very new to iOS programming. Im literally just trying to compile an empty project which as far as I know should work but I'm running into an error:

```
ProcessPCH /users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/USB1-Prefix-gsurnmlnnrebssbippyayakjgjix/USB1-Prefix.pch.pth USB1/USB1-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Volumes/SP UFD U2/USB1"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -iquote /users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/USB1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/USB1.build/USB1-generated-files.hmap -I/users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/USB1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/USB1.build/USB1-own-target-headers.hmap -I/users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/USB1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/USB1.build/USB1-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/USB1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/USB1.build/USB1-project-headers.hmap -I/users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/USB1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/USB1.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/USB1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/USB1.build/DerivedSources -F/users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/USB1-Prefix-gsurnmlnnrebssbippyayakjgjix/USB1-Prefix.pch.dia -c "/Volumes/SP UFD U2/USB1/USB1/USB1-Prefix.pch" -o /users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/USB1-Prefix-gsurnmlnnrebssbippyayakjgjix/USB1-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /users/case4/murphb52/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/USB1-frxarpuqvqeibygmuqixzogxrplz/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/USB1-Prefix-gsurnmlnnrebssbippyayakjgjix/USB1-Prefix.pch.d

fatal error: error in backend: IO failure on output stream.
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Just wondering does anyone have any solutions or ideas at what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any source files at all in the project?

Comment: Im literally creating a new project and clicking play

Comment: Well there are different types of project so please tell me if Xcode created source files for you.

Comment: Sorry yes Im creating a Single-View Application.  
The source files are:  
AppDelegate.h ,  
AppDelegate.m , 
ViewController.m , 
MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard ,  
MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard , 
ViewController.h

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You're most likely out of disk space.  Where is your build folder located?  It might not be allowed to write and causing that error.

Answer (score 4):

Had this issue, tried most things, but in the end an OSX reboot solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Derek is correct. In my case the RAM disk I use for XCode derived data was full.